# 18.04 - Graphics crash when fullscreen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, games, fullscreen

While using 16.04 I was able to play certain games (*ioquake3, lugaru*) in 1920x1080 resolution fullscreen. When I upgraded to 18.04 I had some issues with the proprietary Nvidia drivers as usual but soon everything else worked perfectly. Once I had installed *ioquake3* and tried to played it fullscreen, the computer just froze and started moving extremely slow. The same happens when I fullscreen a high resolution video in VLC. I noticed that when entered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then immediately went back to GDM (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) the problem was gone. Everything flowed nice and smooth just as it was meant to.

This does not happen when playing windowed mode.

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GT216GLM [Quadro FX 880M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:42 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

EDIT: There are some irregularities I've noticed. It doesn't crash when *mplayer* goes fullscreen, for example. I have a feeling that this has to do with hardware acceleration for some reason although I lack the knowledge to make an accurate statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a solution for you though I'm experiencing similar issues... Using the proprietary 390/396 driver, whenever I fullscreen anything GDM crashes and restarts I've tried rolling back to an older kernel to see if that was the culprit but I experience the same problem.

Has to be the graphics driver? Using 18.04/17.10 is fine with older drivers I notice...